# store constant variable on server via .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I would like to store the `INDEX_URL` constant the easiest way possible.

There is a developer site and a normal site. If there is any change on the developer site,
I would like to just copy the entire files but this constant is not the same on the 2 sites.

---

I have made this test:

```
putenv("TEST=TEST");
var_dump(getenv('TEST')); //TEST

//putenv("TEST=TEST");
var_dump(getenv('TEST')); //false
```

It seems it does not store the value.

---

Alternative method:

```
define('__INDEX_URL__',"http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/index.php");
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can save it as environment variable. Put this in .htaccess:

```
SetEnv INDEX_URL http://example.com/index.php
```

And get it in PHP:

```
$indexUrl = getenv('INDEX_URL');
```

Comment: This one seams great but does not work. What can be the reason?

Comment: I think that your web server doesn't allow to override settings. If you are using Apache, make the next in you http config: AllowOverride All

Comment: I have tired AllowOverride All with no success. (see the updated question too)

Comment: Is your .htaccess file working at all? Test it. I am sure that problem in it. Try to add some redirect for example in .htaccess. Check if your script in directory with .htaccess or .htaccess in parent directory. Check Apache config also.

Answer (score 6):

To make switching between hosts automatically You could use SetEnvIf :

.htaccess :

```
SetEnvIf Host host\.com INDEX_URL=http://host.com/index.php
SetEnvIf Host dev\.host\.com INDEX_URL=http://dev.host.com/index_dev.php
```

PHP :

```
$indexUrl = isset($_SERVER['INDEX_URL']) ? $_SERVER['INDEX_URL'] : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
In `.htaccess`, add
`SetEnv HTTP_MYCONSTANT = "My Value"`

Note : Start with Http for security reasons

And get the value on any page like this:
`getenv('HTTP_MYCONSTANT')`